# Bootlooping VFD 600

Tags: boot-loop

I have a Vodafone Smart Prime 7 (VFD600) that is bootlooping since today. It is not Unlocked, rooted or modified in any way. I haven't used it since september, and I have tried wiping data and flashing the stock rom, but no luck.

Comment: what was the error message on formatting /data

Comment: @alecxs no error message.